# I am unable to suggest edits even after the seven-day ban period

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits, rejected-edits, edit-ban

I have suggested several edits that were rejected. (I am aware of the rules that state that the system will ban users from suggesting edits for seven days if they suggest edits that are rejected frequently.)

Why am I unable to suggest an edit even after **seven banned  days**?
My last suggested and rejected edit was submitted on **the 19th of July**. Today is **the 27th**, the **eighth day** of the ban period.

Comment: Perhaps some UTC timing difference? Give it another day perhaps.

Comment: @Bart  If I count the 19th July...then it would now become the 9th day.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a rejected edit from July 21 as well:

> [image]

It leads to "page not found" and does not appear in your activity so it probably means the post you suggested to edit was deleted, but it still counts towards the ban.

Wait one more day and if still banned, update this question.

Comment: Thank you Sha Wiz Dow Ard...I knew that Meta Stack will let me know the Reason...Once Again Thank You..these things are not seen to me so I have posted it here feeling that I was banned for some extra time..

Comment: No problem, I just happen to know some tricks that's all. :)